# How i can match multiple CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

How i can match only if the div playTitleDurationContainer has the class cinema-large and the qualityMarker div ?

Thanks S.

```
<div id="playTitleDurationContainer" class="playTitleDurationContainer cinema-large">
    <div id="qualityMarker" class="qualityMarker">
        <img class="no-border" alt="" src="img.png" width="47" height="30">
    </div>
    <div id="videoTitle" class="videoTitle">Test 1</div>
    <div id="playingTime" class="playingTime">06:11</div>
</div>
```

Example:
If the playTitleDurationContainer has the element i want to change css for the videoTitle and for the PlayingTime one the same time.

Comment: What do you want to select?

Comment: you can try this `#playTitleDurationContainer.playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large { ... }`

Comment: one id `id="videoTitle"` other `class="Titlevideo"`

Comment: Please explain clearly

Comment: First of all, if you are going to have more than one movie, you are going to need to use classes instead of ids. Then... how are you going to get the 'qualityMarker?' Are you using a custom taxonomy in WordPress or something? Either way... although these answers are creative... you are probably doing something wrong before this point if you need to target like this.

Comment: Use this fiddle to give a better explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/P8PA7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
div.playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large > div.qualityMarker{

}
```

Comment: it does only match if the playTitleDurationContainer has the cinema-large and qualityMarker div

Answer (score 0):

> How i can match only if the div `playTitleDurationContainer` has the class cinema-large?

That's easy. Since every `id` should be unique, you could simply use

```
#playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large { ... }
```

> and the qualityMarker div ?

That's not possible, since the [subject selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) is neither implemented nor recommended yet. A workaround is to get `#qualityMarker` with JavaScript and add a class to its parent. In this case you can again combine the classes:

```
#playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large.hasQualityDiv { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
div.playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large > div.qualityMarker ~ .videoTitle,div.playTitleDurationContainer.cinema-large > div.qualityMarker ~ .playingTime {
    /* styling here*/    
}
```